# Do I need to do something about partition alignment when installing Windows XP on a SSD drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, ssd

I just got a new SSD drive (OCZ Vertex 2) and installed Windows 7 on it. Problem is, now I need to install XP also for some legacy applications that I run. I read [here](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_set_up_Windows_on_a_VERTEX#Microsoft_Windows_XP_.28all_service_pack_levels.29), among others, that XP has partition alignment issues when creating a new partition, that can lead to huge performance drops and increase the wear of the drive. The suggested remedy involves tuning the partitions with DISKPART. I was just wondering, will it be OK if I create a new partition from Win7 (which supposedly doesn't suffer from this issue) and then install XP on that?

Comment: Formatting has nothing to do with sector alignment, you still need a 4k aware OS. See this....http://superuser.com/questions/291978/western-digital-green-drive-from-512-byte-sectors-jumpered-to-4k-byte-sectors/291992#291992

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that will work fine. Windows 7 will automatically align the partition properly, and the partition will remain aligned when you install XP onto it.

Comment: What if I migrate Windows 7 from old HDD to new SSD? Do I need to perform alignment and how?

Comment: Windows 7 uses the same alignment for both HDDs and SSDs so as long as you let Windows 7 align the HDD the alignment should be preserved during migration.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that alignment is only relevant for Windows XP. Not sure about Windows Vista though...

Comment: Vista deals with alignment the same way 7 does.

Comment: And all previous versions prior to Vista need to be aligned. Got it, but what about Linux? Which distribution and of which version starts aligning SSDs?