# GNU parted: how to deal with the error about proper aligment of partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning

Here's what I get when partitioning with **parted**:

> The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance

This is one troubling piece that I haven't, somewhat, found a proper answer for, when googling. What does this error mean, how to deal with it and why does it occur?

**NOTE**:

> mkpart p 8192 X

skipping *exactly* **4 MiB** (512x8192) of space before the start of the partition boundaries, makes parted not spew this error message (anything less - does).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note: I am sure SuperUser already has a good answer on this. I couldn't find it, however.)*

Both disks and filesystems divide their space in blocks (sectors, clusters) of a certain size, normally multiples of two in the range 512 B ~ 8192 B.

When a partition is not "aligned" – that is, when a filesystem starts in the middle of a physical sector – writing a single filesystem cluster involves *reading*, updating, and then rewriting *multiple* physical sectors:

```
              1       2       3
fsys:     |-------|-------|-------|
disk:  |-------|--'----|--'----|-------|
           1       2       3       4
```

In the example above, writing filesystem cluster #2 would require the disk controller to read blocks #2 and #3, then write back to the same location (after waiting for the platters to spin almost 360° if it's a hard disk).

But if the partition is aligned, all that's needed is a single write.

- See also JdeBP's FGA: [The gen on disc partition alignment – 4KiB alignment](http://jdebp.eu/FGA/disc-partition-alignment.html#4KiB)
- [Partition Alignment Issues](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/advice.html#alignment) in *gdisk* documentation

Recent high-capacity disks use 4096 B sectors physically (called "Advanced Format"), but the OS sees each sector as 8 sectors 512 B each. Even if the filesystem is aligned to those 512 B sectors, it might still start in the middle of a real 4 kiB sector, resulting in the same problem as above.

- [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/291978/western-digital-green-drive-from-512-byte-sectors-jumpered-to-4k-byte-sectors/291992#291992) has pictures.

To avoid this and related alignment problems in the future, many partitioning programs have started aligning at boundaries as high as 1 MiB (which isn't that much of a loss on terabyte disks anyway).

Comment: interesting read and good info. However, I always use **parted** with a unit of sectors. Also, I have a **3TB** _Hitachi_ drive that has a native sector size of **512** bytes (mostly an exception from comparable drives of the same size). So, as my understanding goes, i can safely ignore this message if I actually partition the drive in sectors that match my physical sector size (no way of shifting?)

Comment: Start sectors must divide by 2048 (when align to 1MiB) what about partitions end sectors? Are they irrelevant ?